# Solving maze using recursion (2 disrections) in java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, maze

i kind of need help on this problem. I want to use recursion to solve a NxN binary matrix. The problem is i think my recursion implementation is somehow not correct. In this problem I'm only allowed to go right and down only. I have checked issafe() method and everything seems to return true or false according to the 1=true and 0=false. if i run the run program, nothing displays. any help would be really appreciated.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int maze[][] = {{1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {1, 1, 0, 1},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0},
                        {1, 1, 1, 2}
        };
Maze rat = new Maze();
rat.solveMaze(maze, 0, 0);



    }

}

public class Maze {
    int maze[][];
    int mazeSize;
    int EXIT=2;

    public Maze() {

        mazeSize=4;
        maze = new int[mazeSize][mazeSize];
    }

    // check is its safe to traverse

    public Boolean isSafe(int x, int y, int maze[][]){
        if (x>=0 && x<mazeSize && y>=0 && y<mazeSize && maze[x][y]==1){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }


    boolean solveMaze(int maze[][],int x,int y){
        int solmaze[][]=    {   {0, 0, 0, 0},
                                {0, 0, 0, 0},
                                {0, 0, 0, 0},
                                {0, 0, 0, 0}};

        if(maze[x][y]==EXIT){
            solmaze[x][y]=1;
            printmaze(solmaze);
            return true;
        }

        if(isSafe(x, y,maze) && maze[x][y]==1){
            solmaze[x][y]=1;
            return true;
        }

        if(isSafe(x, y,maze)==true && solveMaze(maze,x+1,y)==true){// down

            solmaze[x][y]=1;
        }
        if(isSafe(x, y,maze)==true && solveMaze(maze,x,y+1)==true){//right

            solmaze[x][y]=1;
        }
        solmaze[x][y]=0;
        return false;
    }

    void printmaze(int maze[][]){//print maze
        for(int i=0;i<maze.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<maze.length;j++){
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is the solution you are looking for:

```
public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int maze[][] = {{1, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 0, 1},
                {0, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 1, 2}
        };
        Maze rat = new Maze();
        rat.solveAndPrintMaze(maze, 0, 0);
    }

}

public class Maze {
    int maze[][];
    int mazeSize;
    int EXIT=2;

    public Maze() {

        mazeSize=4;
        maze = new int[mazeSize][mazeSize];
    }

    // check is its safe to traverse
    public Boolean isSafe(int x, int y, int maze[][]){
        if (x>=0 && x<mazeSize && y>=0 && y<mazeSize && maze[x][y]>=1){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    int solmaze[][]= {
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0}};

    boolean solveMaze(int maze[][],int x,int y){

        if(maze[x][y]==EXIT){
            solmaze[x][y]=1;
//          printmaze(solmaze);
            return true;
        }

//      if(isSafe(x, y,maze) && maze[x][y]==1){
//          solmaze[x][y]=1;
//          return true;
//      }

        if(isSafe(x+1, y,maze)==true && solveMaze(maze,x+1,y)==true){// down

            solmaze[x][y]=1;
            return true;
        }

        if(isSafe(x, y+1,maze)==true && solveMaze(maze,x,y+1)==true){//right

            solmaze[x][y]=1;
            return true;
        }

        solmaze[x][y]=0;
        return false;
    }

    void printmaze(int maze[][]){//print maze
        for(int i=0;i<maze.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<maze.length;j++){
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    void solveAndPrintMaze(int maze[][],int x,int y) {
        solveMaze(maze, x, y);
        printmaze(solmaze);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first if statement is supposed to be my base case that returns the matrix. if i comment out the printmaze method, then nothing will show up then if it reaches the exit point.

Comment: Because of that I used another method the solveAndPrintMaze, that will guarantee that the solution maze is always printed.

Comment: thanks alot. but can you please explain why my printmaze method isnt applicable.

Comment: Because you printmaze in the end, and at the end the solmaze is not all set for every position. If you debug your code a put a break point in the lines where you set the solmaze you will see that the printmaze executes before that lines.

Comment: Another way to say it: you set a position as being visited AFTER you return from the recursive call to `solveMaze`, so that the whole path isn't filled-in until you get back to the initial call.

Answer (score 0):

On your first call to `solveMaze`, the second `if` is true ((0,0) is safe & there is a 1 there), so you return `true` without having printed anything.

Maybe if you explained what this is intended to do, one could help fix it (which may well be by removing it).

Comment: I'm trying to traverse the matrix using recursion. like the problem rat in the maze

Comment: Fine, but you never get to the recursion because of the `if` statement I identified.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually attempting recursion here. To initiate recursion in the way that you're attempting, you would have to call your solveMaze method from within itself.

I was wrong about that. Correct answer is given by Scott below.

Comment: I did call it here if(isSafe(x, y,maze)==true && solveMaze(maze,x+1,y)==true){// down
   
   solmaze[x][y]=1;
  }